# Can I travel to Australia in less than 2 weeks if I transfer my visa to my new passport?

Tags: visas, australia

[image]

I transferred my visa to my new passport and it’s saying it takes 2 weeks to come, my flight is Sunday I arrive in Sydney Monday at night, I still have my old passport! If I bring that will they let me go into the country because my new one literally arrived two days ago! And the visa will be transferred in 2 weeks! Will I have to push my flight or will I be left?

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. What is your nationality, and what sort of visa is do you have?

Comment: "I still have my old passport!" -- that's great. For everyone else: this is why you need to hold on to your old passport.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but be prepared to be delayed at check-in.

Australia's visas are fully electronic and are linked to your passport number.  You are required to submit your new passport details (via Form 929 or ImmiAccount) when you renew your passport so that your visa can be linked to your new passport number.

When you check in to your flight, the check-in agent will verify your visa details directly with the Australian Government using your new passport number.  If your passport details have not yet been updated, the system will not be able to find your visa and you may be denied boarding.

Therefore, you should bring your old and new passports when you check in.  The check-in agent (if they are aware of the proper procedures) can manually telephone the Border Operations Centre to update your passport details if your Form 929 is not processed in time.  A FAQ on this process can be found [here](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/change-in-situation/passport-details).

You can check whether your visa has been transferred across by using [VEVO](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have-a-visa/check-visa-details-and-conditions/overview) with your new passport details.