# Form 929: No response received from the mailing id, not even automated response

Tags: visas, australia, passport-renewals

My father needs to travel to Australia on an urgent basis, but they recently got their passports renewed and they hold a visitor's visa against their old passport.

I emailed the following address [929@homeaffairs.gov.au], with the copy of Form 929, new passport and old passport. But I did not receive back any email not even the automated reply.

Can we travel without the electronic visa update recently? Is it possible? If not, what is the other fastest process to get this done?

Comment: See related question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122697/can-i-travel-to-australia-in-less-than-2-weeks-if-i-transfer-my-visa-to-my-new-p

Answer (score 5):

You aren’t supposed to receive a reply, you need to log in to your [ImmiAccount](http://www.border.gov.au/immiaccount).

As according to [this SE question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47745/travel-to-australia-with-new-passport):

> According to the Australia Department of Immigration and Border Protection, you need to notify Australia of your new passport before you travel, even if you have a visa label in your old passport. Australian visas are linked to your passport number, and travelers might not have a visa label in their passports at all.
>
> If you read the form instructions for the notification form, it states that you can complete this form online. So you may be able to do this quickly enough to be able to travel.
>
> **Note that the form instructions state that you will not receive a reply. You can log in to [ImmiAccount](http://www.border.gov.au/immiaccount) to check the status.**
>
> If your old passport has a visa label in it, you should bring it with you when you travel. Do not try to remove the label and place it in your new passport.

Notifying them is required of your new passport.

Comment: Thanks @David . The visa was applied offline and hence i am not able to create an immiaccount against the visa (Import application also did not work here) . So updating the details online is not possible in my case .There is no label on the old passport .But the mention of the old passport number is there on the new on .Can that work ?

Comment: @RoshnyJoy I don't know, I only edited Daniil's answer. Perhaps another SE reader will see your question and offer more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to your [ImmiAccount](https://online.immi.gov.au/lusc/login) and inform the changes here.

If you processed your visa application through an agent, then you can import your application using the visa grant number (available on your visa).

Once the application is imported, you can view all the documents that were submitted via your agent. You can fill the form and inform the agency here.